# Can convolutional neural network learn integral operator?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

Given a function

$$
u(x), x\in [0,1]
$$

Say 1D convolutional neural network, we all know it can learn the differential operator.

$$
\partial u/ \partial x \approx D u
$$

But what about the integral operator

$$
\int_0^{x} u(s)ds
$$

My guess is, since CNN operator is homogeneous, so it cannot learn that.

Note that although CNN operator is local, by going deep, it can learns the global interactions.

Answer (score 1):

The convolution function itself is defined as $$(k \ast u)(t) = \int_\infty^\infty k(t-s)\cdot u(s)\ ds$$
where $k$ is the filter. So, trivially, when $k$ is 1 everywhere, you can integrate the input $u$.

There's some details to be aware of here, such as: usually $k$ is only non-zero in a range of values, aka the receptive field. If the bounds of your integral are larger than the receptive field, then of course the convolution layer can't compute it.